# Spacing from left margin for text in sections

Tags: spacing, sectioning, paragraphs

Is it any simple command in LaTeX to add space from left margin for all text in the sections? What I mean by that:

I used the geometry package to set up margins size:

```
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.25cm, right=1.25cm]{geometry}
```

And the result is:

[image]

And now I have to add extra space from left margin but ONLY for the text in the sector (Tables, figures etc. should stay without changes):

[image]

I am familiar with `bindingoffset` but it adds space for the whole document. The point is to move only text in the sector and leave other elements without moving.

Comment: You have the `adjustwidth` environment, from `changepage` to change the margins locally. In my opinion, it would be better to have a wider left margin, and to use this environment  only for figures, &c. You also can enable the section titles  to start in the margin (this is easy with `titlesec` if you use standard document class).